# assign swf as image source in flex at runtime

Tags: apache-flex, flash

In Flex, how to assign swf as image source **at runtime, not embedding it**.

```
[Bindable] public var myImg:String;

<mx:Image id="intImg" source="{myImg}" width="96%" height="96%" />
```

In my application, I fetch image url dynamically from a web service call, and assign it to "myImg".

But until I don't get the response from the web service call, I want to show a loader swf in image control above. I assigned something like:

```
myImg = "assets/AS3.swf";
```

and the path of swf is correct, but it doesn't show up.

---

**UPDATE:**

**The code I've shown above works perfectly in a Flex 3 app but the swf does not show up in a Flex 4 app. Is it because Image control has dropped the support for swf in Flex 4 ?**

Please help me out.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried updating the image source manually  intImg.source="assets/AS3.swf" ?

Comment: tried it, unfortunately doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `SWFLoader` to load SWFs, Image is made for Images...

Comment: thanks for response - I have read that we can assign swf as source of image control. "The value of the source property represents a relative or absolute URL; a ByteArray representing a SWF, GIF, JPEG, or PNG; an object that implements IFlexDisplayObject; ...."

Comment: That's the thing, most of the time your SWF doesn't implement IFlexDisplayObject since it's normally a CS5 swf...

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that your path is correct? Because it should work.

Remember that the path you write (assets/AS3.swf) is relative to the location of your application swf file. So for instance if you're debugging in FlashBuilder/FlexBuilder the file should be located in

```
[yourprojectdirectory]/bin-debug/assets/AS3.swf
```

Non-embedded files are not automatically copied to the bin-debug folder (or the bin-release folder for that matter). So you have to do it manually.

You can use a web debugging proxy - like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) - to see whether the file is found in the path you are using.

Comment: I think SWF support was dropped in the Spark Image. At the very least, it says in the docs to use SWFLoader to load any swf data, hence why it exists in the first place...

Comment: Just checked: works with Spark Image too. Although it doesn't use SWFLoader internally anymore. mx Image does extend directly from SWFLoader though. If all you want to do is display a loader animation, both will do just fine. As to why: you might want the loading animation to be displayed with the same skin as the eventual image.

Comment: @RIAstar thanks for the response, I tried your suggestion in a Flex3 app and it worked, but in my Flex 4 app, it doesn't show the swf.

Comment: That's really odd. Different version of FlashBuilder/FlexBuilder perhaps? I seem to remember that there were some changes in how relative paths from the main app are referenced. If you put your assets folder outside of the src folder, in one version you had to reference the files as "../assets/img.jpg" whereas now you can just do "assets/img.jpg".

Comment: @RIAstar - good catch. "different version of FlashBuilder/FlexBuilder" seems to be the culprit in my case. anyways I'll need to try compile my app in different Flash Builder version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally refactor mx:Image to s:Image in your Flex 3 to Flex 4.5 migration?

For Spark Image, it could be that you need to reference the symbol name in the SWF.

I find this works:

```
<s:Image source="@Embed(source='path.swf', symbol='name')" ...
```

Seems like a bad practice, though - unlike mx:Image which would load the SWF natively, Spark Image is intended for bitmap data.

Answer (score -3):

For **Flex 4**, I think ONLY SWF with **AS3** (AVM2*) support was dropped.
Try with **AS1 & AS2**, that run within AVM1*

**AVM (ActionScript Virtual Machine)*